# Forecasts based on other forecasts

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I was given 2 forecasts: Scenario 1 and Scenario 2 for EU GDP. How can I calculate 2 scenarios (forecasts) for Germany GDP?
a) There is a strong correlation between (historic) EU GDP and Germany GDP
b) EU GDP is impacted by Germany GDP.

At first I thought that I can predict Germany GDP using sARIMA and later to apply shocks from scenario 1 or scenario 2 to the predicted germany gdp data. However, I am not sure how to make different shocks between EU and Germany, should I scal them using correlation? Any ideas or hints are welcome.

[edit] Added data [CSV files](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Am9f1Ox4hcd-4AbTb5UdFwfNx3xY)

There are 2 CSVs:

a) Example_historic.csv with historic data for Germany and EU

b) Example_forecasts.csv with 2 scenarios for the EU.

Goal: how to build 2 forecasts for Germany?

Comment: Please post the forecasts you were given ... and also post the historical data for both series

Comment: your two scenarios seem identical i.e. the predictions for the euro gdp are the same for the next 12 quarters.

Comment: Just to clarify: data between 1980 and 2018 are historic.
2019 - 2021 are forecasts. There are 2 scenarios for EU GDP and 2 missing for Germany.

Comment: They look the same to me ... can you simply post these 24 values   12 quarterly values  for each scenario over 3 years

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U948w.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U948w.png) The second nd third rows are your future values for the euro gdp. They are the same.

Comment: I have splitted the file into 2. The previous version might be confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I introduced your 156 months of data to AUTOBOX which developed a SARIMAX model [How to predict the next number in a series while having additional series of data that might affect it?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/398489/how-to-predict-the-next-number-in-a-series-while-having-additional-series-of-dat/398496#398496) .

The cross-correlation analysis using the pre-whitened series suggested a contemporaneous relationship between the two series. A few anomalous data points were detected along with two downwards level shifts viz 1993/2 and 2006/2 .

The useful equation is here [image] with residual plot here [image]

The Actual/Fit and Forecast using scenario 1 is [image] with forecasts here [image]

while using scenario 2 we get [image] and [image]

The model is presented here [image]